# How to data in segue using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to pass my array from my first to my second ViewController.
In the end of my first VC I tried to pass it like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let secondVC = ViewController2()
    secondVC.passengers2 = passengers
    print(secondVC.passengers2)

    print(passengers)
    }
```

"passengers" is my first array in "ViewController.swift" and "passengers2" my sewcond array in "ViewController2.swift".

When I go over to my second VC, the console tells me, that "passengers" and "passengers2" have the same value, but as soon as I am in "ViewController2.swift", "passengers2" is emtpy for some reason.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: " let secondVC = ViewController2()" That's because you are creating a whole new object and not using the one that is at the end of the segue. `let secondVC = segue.destination as ViewController2 ` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you instantiate a new ViewController2 object, which is never used.

You want to use the destination view controller that is inside your segue object, like that :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController2 {
        destinationVC.passengers2 = passengers
    }
}
```